# Set label text on a form from the value of a combobox on another form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Form1 which has a comboBox with various options. Form2 is opened from Form1 via a button click.

I want a label on Form2 to have its text set to the value of the comboBox on Form1.

I come from VBA so tried

```
this.label1.Text = Form1.comboBox1.Text;
```

But this doesn't work. Whats the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: Form1 will not be a globally accessible variable, you will need to pass the form1 varaible to form2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass combobox text to constructor of `Form2`:

```
public Form2(string something)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.label1.Text = something; // initialize label text
}
```

When opening Form2:

```
using(var form2 = new Form2(comboBox1.Text)) // pass
{
   form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Probably, constructor chaining i.e. `public Form2(string something): this() {label1.Text = something;}` is a better way to avoid  `InitializeComponent();` call